# Android bluetooth icon on notification bar

Tags: android, bluetooth, icons, android-notification-bar

I'm now testing Bluetooth application.
But the thing is, the icon on notification bar doesn't turn into active mode(instead of just normal mode and no sound additionally) even they can communicate properly

Is there any specific way to make it an active icon? or Am I aware of it in a wrong way?

I tried proxy mode as a bluetoothHeadset mode to check out.
Thank you in advance.